# Storing the values inside temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

How to put results of below query in the temp table?

The below query gives me some result set. I need to store the result set in temp table so I can perform some joins with that temp table

```
Declare @cols nvarchar(max),@query nvarchar(max)
select @cols = 
stuff( ( select  ',[' + Ltrim(rtrim(costelement)) +']' from WECCostElementsCalculation  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'');

select @query= 
'with T as 
(select wch.WECCostElementHeaderID,wceyb.WECCostElementsBreakUpID ,wch.WECCostID,WCEYB.ServiceTypeID,WCEYB.WarrantyCoverageID,wecec.CostElement,weceb.Cost
 from  WECCostElementsHeader WCH inner join  WECCostElementsYearBreakUp WCEYB on WCH.WECCostElementHeaderID
 =WCEYB.WECCostElementHeaderID INNER JOIN WECCostElementsBreakUp wecEB on wecEB.WECCostElementsBreakUpID=WCEYB.WECCostElementsBreakUpID  
 left join WECCostElementsCalculation wecec on wecEB.WECCostElementID = wecec.WECCostElementID
 ) 
 select * from T
 PIVOT
 (SUM(Cost) FOR CostElement IN ('+@cols+')) as pvt'

 exec sp_executesql @query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SELECT INTO:

```
select * 
into ##temp 
from T
PIVOT
```

Then after `exec sp_executesql @query`

```
SELECT * FROM ##temp
```

In case of using temp table you should add on the top of your main query or its dynamic part:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'##temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##temp;
```

Comment: Declaring it as a global temporary table is risky, especially if it's going to be called "temp", which is too common. Also, what about subsequent executions of the stored procedure? He would have to modify the query since the table will exist after the 1st execution.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Any other name, it is not a concern. It could be generated dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create the table into which you're going to store the data returned by the stored procedure. Make sure the table has the exact columns as the result set from the stored procedure.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (WECCostElementHeaderID int, etc. ... )
```

Now, to insert the data into the table all you need to do is:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable
exec sp_executesql @query
```

Just for quick testing purposes:

```
create table #TempTable (id int)

declare @query nvarchar(100)

set @query = 'select 1 as id union select 2'

insert into #TempTable
exec sp_executesql @query

select *
from #TempTable
```

Comment: OP uses dynamic SQL and he don't know the column names and there datatypes.

Comment: @gofr1 You're right about that, but that wasn't his question :) Maybe he's always going to get the same columns, or maybe the columns he will select will change very little over time and he can afford to update the table once in a while.

Comment: Maybe :) It is just a note.

Comment: @gofr1 We'll see what he goes with.

Comment: Hey gofr1 is right .I don't know column names and there datatypes.I am stuck how can i insert the data in result set which is dynamically generated  to temp table.For instance @cols generates many elements which i need to store it in temp table..

Answer (score 1):

you have to create a temporary table and simply put `Insert INTO #Temporary_Table(Col1,Col2,....)` before `exec sp_executesql @query` statement.
just like below:-

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@query NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @cols = stuff((
            SELECT ',[' + Ltrim(rtrim(costelement)) + ']'
            FROM WECCostElementsCalculation
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '');

CREATE TABLE #Temporary_table(Col1 datatype,Col2 datatype,Col3.....)


SELECT @query = 'with T as 
(select wch.WECCostElementHeaderID,wceyb.WECCostElementsBreakUpID ,wch.WECCostID,WCEYB.ServiceTypeID,WCEYB.WarrantyCoverageID,wecec.CostElement,weceb.Cost
 from  WECCostElementsHeader WCH inner join  WECCostElementsYearBreakUp WCEYB on WCH.WECCostElementHeaderID
 =WCEYB.WECCostElementHeaderID INNER JOIN WECCostElementsBreakUp wecEB on wecEB.WECCostElementsBreakUpID=WCEYB.WECCostElementsBreakUpID  
 left join WECCostElementsCalculation wecec on wecEB.WECCostElementID = wecec.WECCostElementID
 ) 
 select * from T
 PIVOT
 (SUM(Cost) FOR CostElement IN (' + @cols + ')) as pvt'

INSERT INTO #Temporary_table(Col1,Col2,Col3.....)
EXEC sp_executesql @query

SELECT * FROM #Temporary_table
```

Comment: The number of columns is dynamic. So you can not create table for results withing main query - it should be in dynamic part. In that case the datatypes of columns should be obtained from system tables...

Comment: Hi  @cols in pivot section is generated dynamically ..How can i create temp table for the same.